# Passing json parameters in a GET method of a httpwebrequest

Tags: c#-4.0, restful-url

I have been given a get method for a restful service but the method has parameters that need to be passed to  get a response.

Using Httpwebrequest the GetResponse method doesn't allow for passing on of parameters with Get and likewise with Stream.

So, my question is how do I pass Json parameters on a GET method with Httpwebrequest in C#?

Comment: `WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/?param=" + (WebUtility.UrlEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param))));`?

Comment: Thanks but is this passing as a querystring? If so, I sooner not do so

Comment: GET requests _are_ query string parameters. Sure you're not confusing http verbs?

Comment: I have normally passed parameters with streamwriter and wondered if it was possible to do the same

Comment: In a POST/PUT request, certainly. But a GET has no body, so the server isn't observing anything past the headers.

Comment: Ok so all is to append the json to the URL and then carry on as normal?

Comment: If it's a GET request, yes. Though, IMHO, it's odd to place JSON in the parameter (this is usually the body of a POST request). However, if the API is a GET and requires JSON, query parameter is the way.

Comment: Cheers I will try tomorrow morning

Comment: Not a problem.  I'll write up a formal answer so you have something to accept.

Comment: Can you please post the code that worked for you? I am stuck with this.