# Getting the result from API with json param

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, webapi

For now I was able to pull the return value from the api using plain web link without any parameter being pass on it.

Here is my sample working script:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myServer:1111/Test/MESService.svc/web");
req.Method = "GET";
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("appUser", "appPass");

var waferRes = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
var waferStream = waferRes.GetResponseStream();
string result = "";
List<JObject> data = new List<JObject>();
JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(waferStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(Json(result));
```

But this time I need to pass a json parameter on the link to get the result and I'm not so sure how this can handle on my current call.

Here is the sample param that I need to pass:

```
{
  "request": {
    "paramA": "DummyA",
    "paramB": "DummyB",
  }
}
```

Any suggestion/comments if there is way to handle on this case

Comment: If you're using the GET method to pass a JSON parameter, there's already other answers on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925268/passing-json-parameters-in-a-get-method-of-a-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 1):

Usually json is passed in the request body. However, the body has no semantic meaning for the GET request. But you can do that with a query parameter json, for example:

```
http://myServer:1111/Test/MESService.svc/web/?json={%22request%22:{%22paramA%22:%22DummyA%22,%22paramB%22:%22DummyB%22}}
```

Comment: "?json=" extension at the end is always required? and can I use different naming convention on that?

Comment: @Rockn'Roll you can use any name for the parameter: “?param1=“, “?body=“, etc.

Comment: More about query string: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: I dont get it, how did you transform my current json format: {
  "request": {
    "paramA": "DummyA",
    "paramB": "DummyB",
  }
}  into this: {%22request%22:{%22paramA%22:%22DummyA%22,%22paramB%22:%22DummyB%22}} di you have a generator that I could refer? is it requred when I need to pass it via url request?

Comment: I just convert a json string into a url-encoded string. The main reason for this is to escape characters. To do this in your code, you can use `WebUtility.UrlEncode`